# Creation of a Solution of Liquid Latex + Sodium Caseinate with Polyvinyl Alcohol

Tags: solubility, alcohols, mixtures, rubber

I am going to be experimenting with creating different types of liquid latex formulations, primarily for the purposes of increasing shear strength and tear resistance, as well as just general exploration of various modifications of plastic properties that can be achieved.

Unfortunately, I am a hobbyist, and have zero training or background in chemistry. I have purchased liquid latex and various other ingredients, and am going to be creating various different mixtures of each very soon. However, I also want this project to serve as a jumping off point for my own study of chemistry in general. e.g. I don't simply wish to remain a hobbyist making random mixtures, but want to understand more of the chemical theory behind what I'm doing.

Issue is, I don't know what technical terms I need to know to begin looking up the proper subjects for this project online. To that end, I have some very specific questions I would like to ask:

1. Is Polyvinyl Alcohol likely to be suitable as an emulsifier between liquid latex and sodium caseinate? I've done research on emulsions, but most of what I can find involves oil-water, oil-wax, or wax-water type emulsions.
2. Is there some sort of basic theory of emulsions or resource of that nature that would help me determine emulsion suitability between any number of different classes of chemicals? What is it called? Without the proper terms, I'm basically flailing blind online. :(
3. In previous test procedures, I extracted micellar casein from heated milk using vinegar, and dissolved the casein into a solution of sodium hydroxide and calcium chloride. However, I just put general amounts and hoped for the best. I know that there is a way to calculate how much calcium chloride and sodium hydroxide would be needed to precisely dissolve the micellar casein with no excess chemicals in the solution.
4. Unfortunately, I do not know what this process is called or how to about researching it. But I have seen strange equations with characters on one side, an arrow in the middle, and characters on the other side. I would like to start learning what this is called.

I would very much like to thank you guys for your time. I may be making a lot of very wrong base assumptions, but one has to start somewhere. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.